# Httpclient isn`t working on Android 5.0(Lollipop)

Tags: java, android, mobile, httpclient, emulation

Im trying to send a string with GET, and I have try as well with POST but nothing isn`t working,

this is my code

```
HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();

// Create URL string
String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:2711/RequestsHandler.ashx?bulbStatus=off";
//Log.i("httpget", URL);

try {
    String SetServerString = "";

    // Create Request to server and get response



    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL);

    HttpResponse responseGet = Client.execute(httpget);
    HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();


    content.setText(SetServerString);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    content.setText("Fail!");
}
```

I have tried all the local host example 10.0.0.2 10.0.3..... what ever that you can think of 
I did all the permissions on the manifest (2)

I have check this on a real server( that works ) nothing happen.
I Think the problem is that the string isn`t send to the server ( I have check it its the problem)
please someone can help me  ?

Comment: Are you using an emulator or a real device to test this?

Comment: Try printing the exception to logcat to find out more information of what is going wrong w/ `Log.e("SOMETAG", ex.getMessage(), ex);`

Comment: yes Im using emulator but I tried a real device as well